# Proving The Nested Radical

Tags: nested-radicals

> For $a>b^2$, prove that $\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+\cdots}}}} = \sqrt{a-\dfrac34b^2}-\dfrac12b$.

Attempt:
After assuming the value of the nested radicals to be $S$, I got $$S = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{a-S^2}{b}\right)^2-a}{b},$$ but now I don't have any idea to solve $S$. The result must be the RHS and hence this will prove the equation above.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you got to can be rearranged to
\begin{eqnarray*}
S^4-2aS^2-b^3S+a^2-ab^2=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Lucky for us this can be factorised to
\begin{eqnarray*}
(S^2+bS+b^2-a)(S^2-bS-a)=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
The first bracket will now give you the formula you require.

Comment: Yeah, the first one leads me to the RHS. What about the second bracket? By taking plus sign after applying quadratic formula, are there actually two answers?